# Recording all clicks and interactions on my website

Tags: javascript, python, html, web

I would like to document all clicks and interactions by user on my web software.
With this data I would like to analyze and track the user behavior (to improve the usability).

Is it necessary to implement this functionality or do scripts/code which record the users clicks in the background already exist?

Comment: Google analytics event tracking springs to mind https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Answer (score 1):

http://www.google.com/analytics/

Considered Analytics? Does everything you need as far as I can see?

Comment: Does googleanalytics considerably affect web performance and load times?

Comment: The latest versions have been totally asynchronous I believe. Minimal impact, with the exception of initial download of the .js file.

Comment: Ah ok...then I guess loading 8 lines of javascript is not too demanding.