# Recording all user interactions on a webpage using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a web project, soon to be released in beta phase. I need to record every single activity that the user is doing on the webpage like:

- Page scrolls
- Clicks to internal page, and follow it there.
- Text entry

I need to capture these events along with their relative time of occurrence. Ideally, playable video for a user session. I researched, but I get solutions that allow only click events to be capture, without relative timing info.

I feel, it should not be very difficult to record user interactions and a parser that consumes json data like this, should be able to replay the video:

```
[
    {
        "time": 0,
        "page": "/page1",
        "event": "new_page",
        "locXY": [50,23]
    },
    {
        "time": 3.45,
        "page": "/page1",
        "event": "scroll",
        "locXY": [50,400]
    },
    {
        "time": 0,
        "page": "/page2",
        "event": "click",
        "locXY": [70,450]
    }
]
```

Comment: i think this link will hep somewhat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012611/recording-all-clicks-and-interactions-on-my-website

Comment: It is more complex than you might think as for every element on the page "clicks" are simply recorded things, they are events yes but they have no other data except the element that was clicked and maybe some page metadata, recording userscrolls is a bad idea as you'll have thousands within a few seconds if it isn't normalized. For your problem I would use [JS localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) tho - it will keep your data on the client pc through pageloads which solves the problem of storing the data anyways.

Comment: That's not a good idea as @SidneyLiebrand said, but is worst the relative timing, because when you change the page you want to restart the counter... that's unrelativize all your times

Comment: for the scroll recording one could simply record the time the action started, the page position and the time the action ended and the new position. Then it would not be too hard to animate this (normalized).

Answer (score 1):

On each click event you should request `Date.now` to achieve your timestamp. Then you should save that in a different `var` called old time. Next time the user clicks you can do `curTime - prevTime` to get a difference in time. You could expand this with an initial time. That way you can see how much time it has been since the first click by doing `curTime - initTime`.

Define prevTime and initTime outside your clickListeners.

So in short:

```
//first click:
var curTime = Date.now;
prevTime = curTime;
initTime = curTime;

//Second click:
var curTime = Date.now;
var deltaTime = prevTime - curTime;
var timeSinceInit = initTime - curTime;

// define the new previous timestamp.
prevTime = curTime;

// then parse the data
{
    "time": deltaTime,
    "timeStamp": timeSinceInit,
    "page": "/page1",
    "event": "click",
    "locXY": [mouseX,mouseY]
}
```

EDIT:

Just came to me that you should probably [throttle](https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls) this. Otherwise you'll be recording way to much data and it'll be heavy for your website.

Comment: small edit, forgot you have to set the new prevTime, otherwise you would be comparing to the initial time.